# Problem loading the previously used libraries in R

Tags: r, package, installation-package

I was trying to use these libraries:

```
library(kernlab)  
library(kknn)  
library(tidyverse)  
library(ggplot2)  
library(dplyr)  
library(magrittr)  
library(caret) 
library(e1071) 
library(class)
```

They worked before.

After I clear the environment, I can no longer load the libraries.

Here is the error message I have:

```
install.packages("kernlab")

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently 
installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of 
Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/fiona/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/kernlab_0.9-32.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2513530 bytes (2.4 MB)
downloaded 2.4 MB
```

Any help is appreciated.

I downloaded the RStudio and Rtools again. It still didn't install the packages properly.

Comment: This is not an error but a warning. Your package will be installed.

Comment: What indication do you have Fiona that packages cannot be loaded? As UseR10085 said above, what you show above is not an error, and it looks like `kernlab` should have been installed successfully. If it does not load for you, then there is likely some text after the `downloaded` line that better indicates if/where there are problems. The `.zip` library file means it is a binary package (for windows), so no compiling should be required, so not having Rtools should not be a problem.

Comment: If you're still having problems, though ... since you're running a slightly older version of R (4.2), you will need Rtools 4.2 (see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), and generally it should be installed in the root of the C drive, likely `C:/Rtools42/`. If that directory is not there and/or you have tried a different version of Rtools, then that needs to be fixed.